# Exclude Post ID from Wordpress Query

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have created a wordpress query and I am trying to exclude one post with the id of 1293.

Here is the query I have written so far:

```
<?php 
$my_query = new WP_Query(array (
'post__not_in' => array(1293), 
'post_type' => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => '100'
));
?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 13):

`post__not in` expects an array. Try the following:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array (
    'post__not_in' => array(1293), 
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '100'
));
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't work, the product still shows

Comment: Yup its definitely correct, i will edit the top to show you the full code I am using

Comment: Please echo `$my_query->request` and post it here.

Comment: the code @Merguez posted is spot on. Using this query should exclude post 1293

Comment: I agree, it should do but its not

Comment: @Merguez - string(249) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (0) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100"

Comment: this is strange, I've copied your code and the `$my_query->request` looks like: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID NOT IN (1293) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 100

Comment: what Wordpress version are you using?

Comment: It's version 3.6.1 and the client wont allow us to upgrade.

Comment: I know this may sound silly, but try to add another elements in the exclude array. eg: `'post__not_in' => array(1293, 0) `.

Comment: @AlanCarr This is strange, the exclusion is not reflected in the query. Can you please deactivate all plugins and test again?

Comment: Tried it. Would it matter that the product post_type is being used by woocommerce?

Comment: Maybe, try it. It would be bad design of woocommerce, but as i said: try it.